# create product image attribute in magento2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I am trying to create product attribute of image type.
  I am already created one custom attribute group and some other attribute in it but image type attribute doesn't look good.

[image]

InstallData.php

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'my_attribute_image',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'backend' => 'My\Test5\Model\Attribute\Product\Image',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'My Attribute Image7',
                'input' => 'image',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'group' =>'My custom group',
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => 0,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
```

My\Test5\Model\Attribute\Product\Image.php

```
class Image extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend
{

    protected $_uploaderFactory;
    protected $_filesystem;
    protected $_fileUploaderFactory;
    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory
    ) {
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function afterSave($object)
    {
        $value = $object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getName() . '_additional_data');

        if (empty($value) && empty($_FILES)) {
            return $this;
        }

        if (is_array($value) && !empty($value['delete'])) {
            $object->setData($this->getAttribute()->getName(), '');
            $this->getAttribute()->getEntity()->saveAttribute($object, $this->getAttribute()->getName());
            return $this;
        }

        $path = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(
            DirectoryList::MEDIA
        )->getAbsolutePath(
            'catalog/product/'
        );

        try {

            $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $this->getAttribute()->getName()]);
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $result = $uploader->save($path);

            $object->setData($this->getAttribute()->getName(), $result['file']);
            $this->getAttribute()->getEntity()->saveAttribute($object, $this->getAttribute()->getName());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            if ($e->getCode() != \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader::TMP_NAME_EMPTY) {
                $this->_logger->critical($e);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

It's save image perfectly at front at

`Magento_Root/pub/catalog/product`

But cann't `display/delete` at admin in product tab.because It's find image at 
`{base_url}/catalog/product/my_image.jpg`

So it's look like miss "pub" in url. Anyone wants to suggest another way or correction in my code.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I am getting 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'catalog_product_entity_file'. How do we add table catalog_product_entity_file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Potential Bug in Magento2

I found a few problems in `Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Image.php` with the function called `_getUrl`. Override that function by performing the following steps:

**Step1: di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Image" type="<Vendor>\<Module>\Block\Product" />    
</config>
```

**Step2: Vendor/Module/Block/Product.php**

```
<?php
namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Block;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Image
{
    protected function _getUrl()
    {
        $url = false;
        if ($this->getValue()) {
            $url = $this->_urlBuilder->getBaseUrl(['_type' => 
                \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
            ]) . 'catalog/product/' . $this->getValue();
        }
        return $url;
    }

    protected function _toHtml()
        {
            $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Image'));
            return parent::_toHtml();
        }

}
```

Comment: I created bug issue in github - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6961