# make a custom attribute on catalog to upload a file

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3, file-upload

I want to upload a file from admin side for a user to show on product description page.I just want to make a  file uploaded for now on admin. In store->attribute.  how to achieve this in magento2 ?

I need something like this but its not for file upload

```
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162113/magento-2-add-product-attribute-programmatically
```

I found a extension maybe for same thing  , how I can check this ?

```
https://github.com/jahvi/FileUploadAttribute
```

Comment: https://github.com/jahvi/FileUploadAttribute //this is for magento1.Check this:https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/141637/24878

Comment: @akgola I didnt really get how it will create a file uploador for me ? :(

Comment: https://github.com/JyotiranjanBiswal/magento-2-create-attribute  and what about this  ? @akgola

Comment: this is good but you can only create int,varchar... but not file upload type.

Comment: @akgola  then what to do ? :( guide please