# magento 2 : product attribute file upload

Tags: magento2, backend

in magento 2 i want to add custom pdf to my product attribute,  i tried creating new attibute in product but can not find file upload in same ,can any one help from where can i enable this settings.
i can see only below options.

[image]

Comment: This topic seems to be helpful
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140347/show-value-of-product-attribute-of-type-file-in-magento2-backend/141637#141637

Answer (score 2):

I tried the same thing last week and achieved here I have added a complete module for file upload attribute.

https://github.com/mukdam/magento2-customfileupload-attribute

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: i add your module but after creating and assigning attribute to attribute set, its not showing on product form.

Comment: which error you got can you share

Comment: no error, its just not showing,

Comment: have you assigned in attribute set

Comment: yes attribute is assigned to attribute set.

Comment: @PrinceYadav, getting this error "Addon\Attributeupload\Plugin\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable doesn't exist", can you please upload the working module

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/141637/48571

I am adding the code from that answer so you can get it from here in case the link gets broken.

**Magento2** way is to use UI components and PHP Modifiers

- [Customize Product Creation Form](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/customize_product.html)
- [About PHP modifiers in UI components](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_modifier_concept.html)

Create 3 files:

`etc/adminhtml/di.xml` - dependency injection configuration for adminhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="your_module_datasheet" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Datasheet</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">150</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

`your_module_datasheet` can be any name.

With `sortOrder` from 10 to 50 it didn't work for me. `$meta` variable in Modifier was empty.

`Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Datasheet.php` - php modifier

```
<?php   
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

/**
 * Data provider for "Datasheet" field of product page
 */
class Datasheet extends AbstractModifier
{
    /**
     * @param LocatorInterface            $locator
     * @param UrlInterface                $urlBuilder
     * @param ArrayManager                $arrayManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        ArrayManager $arrayManager
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }

    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $fieldCode = 'datasheet';
        $elementPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath($fieldCode, $meta, null, 'children');
        $containerPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath(static::CONTAINER_PREFIX . $fieldCode, $meta, null, 'children');

        if (!$elementPath) {
            return $meta;
        }

        $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
            $containerPath,
            $meta,
            [
                'children'  => [
                    $fieldCode => [
                        'arguments' => [
                            'data' => [
                                'config' => [
                                    'elementTmpl'   => 'Vendor_Module/grid/filters/elements/datasheet',
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );

        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

`view/adminhtml/web/template/grid/filters/elements/datasheet.html` - knockout js template

```
<!-- ko if: $parent.source.data.product[code] -->
<div>
    <!-- todo: dynamically get path to file from config or controller -->
    <a attr="href: '/pub/media/datasheet'+$parent.source.data.product[code]" text="$parent.source.data.product[code]"></a>
    <label attr="for: uid+'_delete'">
        <!-- todo: generate name -->
        <input type="checkbox" attr="name: 'product['+code + '_delete]', id: uid+'_delete', form: formId">
        <span data-bind="i18n:'Delete'"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<input class="admin__control-file" type="file" data-bind="
    hasFocus: focused,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled,
        form: formId
    }"
/>
```

It is still looks dirty to me and a lot of things to improve.

### Alternatives

I found some interesting files, which can bring you other ideas how to solve it:

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml`

```
<item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
```

`vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition.xml`

```
<fileUploader class="Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Media">
```

Comment: i treid but this is not working, can u tell path of "Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Datasheet.php"

Comment: You have to create this class in your module

Path would be `Vendor/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Datasheet.php`

Comment: @DineshYadav, possible to share the git link to download the module?