# Magento 2 custom product image attribute save issue

Tags: magento2

Magento ver.: 2.2.2

I have created custom image attribute. This is displaying perfectly. But when I upload an image and save product, it's not saving. When I have debugged my code, I have found an issue. My image attribute value display null value every time in my model file(**Magetest\Test\Model\Attribute\Product\Image**).

[image]

Here is my code.

**app/code/Magetest/Test/Setup/InstallData.php**

```
    <?php
namespace Magetest\Test\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    protected $categorySetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\TypeFactory $eavTypeFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\AttributeFactory $attributeFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory $attributeSetFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\GroupFactory $attributeGroupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeManagement $attributeManagement,
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory $groupCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
        $this->_eavTypeFactory = $eavTypeFactory;
        $this->_attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
        $this->_attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        $this->_attributeGroupFactory = $attributeGroupFactory;
        $this->_attributeManagement = $attributeManagement;
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->_groupCollectionFactory = $groupCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $groupName = 'Custom Product Image Upload';
        $attributes = [
            'custom_product_image' => [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'backend' => 'Magetest\Test\Model\Attribute\Product\Image',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Upload Custom Image',
                'input' => 'image',
                'class' => '',
                'group' => $groupName,
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => null,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => '',
                'is_used_in_grid'       => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid'    => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false
            ]
        ];

        $categorySetup = $this->_categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        foreach ($attributes as $code => $params)
            $categorySetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $code, $params);

        $this->sortGroup($groupName, 11);
    }

    private function sortGroup($attributeGroupName, $order)
    {
        $entityType = $this->_eavTypeFactory->create()->loadByCode('catalog_product');
        $setCollection = $this->_attributeSetFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $setCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_id', $entityType->getId());

        foreach ($setCollection as $attributeSet)
        {
            $group = $this->_groupCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', $attributeSet->getId())
                ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_group_name', $attributeGroupName)
                ->getFirstItem()
                ->setSortOrder($order)
                ->save();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**app/code/Magetest/Test/Model/Attribute/Product/Image.php**

```
<?php
namespace Magetest\Test\Model\Attribute\Product;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Image extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend
{

    protected $_uploaderFactory;
    protected $_filesystem;
    protected $_fileUploaderFactory;
    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory
    ) {
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        echo $this->getAttribute()->getName();
        //Out Put: custom_product_image
        echo '<br>';
        var_dump($object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getName()));
        //Out Put: NULL
        var_dump($this->getAttribute()->getName() . '_additional_data');
        //Out Put: NULL
        var_dump($object->getData('name'));
        //Out Put: string(16) "Joust Duffle Bag"
        exit;
        $value = $object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getName() . '_additional_data');

        if (empty($value) && empty($_FILES)) {
            return $this;
        }

        if (is_array($value) && !empty($value['delete'])) {
            $object->setData($this->getAttribute()->getName(), '');
            $this->getAttribute()->getEntity()->saveAttribute($object, $this->getAttribute()->getName());
            return $this;
        }

        $path = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('catalog/product/');

        try {

            $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $this->getAttribute()->getName()]);
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $result = $uploader->save($path);

            $object->setData($this->getAttribute()->getName(), $result['file']);
            $this->getAttribute()->getEntity()->saveAttribute($object, $this->getAttribute()->getName());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            if ($e->getCode() != \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader::TMP_NAME_EMPTY) {
                $this->_logger->critical($e);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can find answer to it here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170186/add-an-image-product-attribute-in-magento-2-in-module-setup

Comment: @shireen Thanks for replay. It's display in "media image" section. I want to display image upload button in my custom section. Please check my screenshot for more detail.

Comment: @Vithal Bariya any other files used or not, if used share code.

Comment: @SureshChikani Other file is not used, Only use basic module required file like registration.php , Data.php, module.xml etc.

Comment: Even I tried this code, but not saving the image.

Comment: @VithalBariya did you get solution for this? If yes, would you like share, so it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the upload action. Check with below steps if anything you have missed.

Step:-1

Create a InstallData.php file on location vendor\Module\Setup

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;

    /**
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {
        /**
         * EAV setup factory.
         *
         * @var EavSetupFactory
         */
        private $_eavSetupFactory;
        protected $categorySetupFactory;

        /**
         * Init.
         *
         * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
         */
        public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, \Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
        {
            $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
            $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         *
         * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
         */
        public function install(
            ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
            ModuleContextInterface $context
        ) {
            /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
            $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $setup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);         
            $setup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'custom_image', [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Custom Image',
                    'input' => 'image',
                    'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Image',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 9,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'group' => 'General Information',
                ]
            );
        }
    }
```

Step:-2

Create a product_form.xml file on location Package\Custom_Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="custom_image">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="module/product_image/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Step:-3

Add below code in Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Image\Upload">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ProductImageUpload</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\ProductImageUpload" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">catalog/tmp/product</argument>
        <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">catalog/product</argument>
        <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
            <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
            <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
            <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Step:-4

Create Upload.php file on location Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Image

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Image;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * Adminhtml Product Image Upload Controller
 */
class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Image uploader
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader
     */
    protected $imageUploader;

    /**
     * Uploader factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory
     */
    private $uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * Media directory object (writable).
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
     */
    protected $mediaDirectory;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * Core file storage database
     *
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database
     */
    protected $coreFileStorageDatabase;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * Upload constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->coreFileStorageDatabase = $coreFileStorageDatabase;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * Check admin permissions for this controller
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Vendor_Module::product');
    }

    /**
     * Upload file controller action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('custom_image');
            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

Try if this helps you!

Comment: Hello Shireen, Thanks for help. I have try your code But it's not working. Image not saved.